# Hurdle in OFFSET function example

Tags: microsoft-excel

I intend to get Smell for Black Color which will be Dirty. Got to know about this formula from a tutorial and applied it:

= OFFSET($C$1, MATCH($B$7, color_,0),0)

It will help to know what is the exact function of $C$1 in the above formula. Is it to move one column to the right as search operation for smell is one column to the right of color? But the same could have been accomplished by smell_ named range. Also, why the output is Citrus and how to get instead Dirty.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this training video on the use of OFFSET and INDEX https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF-HUCToajo - it will help a lot with understanding the fundamental concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [OFFSET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66),

- $C$1: is your reference or your starting point
- `MATCH($B$7, color_,0)`: is the number of rows below the reference
- 0 : is the number of columns to the right of the reference

I assume that the range of your table color_ is from B1 to B6. If my assumption is correct, then `MATCH($B$7, color_,0)` returns 2. So from C1 move 2 rows down which is C3. C3's value is Citrus. That is why you get that result.

You have 2 possibilities to get the correct result:

- Change `MATCH($B$7, color_,0)` to `MATCH($B$7, color_,0)-1`
- Or the range of color_ must be from B2 to B6

Comment: Why $C$1 is used. Why not C1. It will help to know the use of $ in this context. I have seen $ used to fix values in a formula. In this example, reference or starting point is one field C1. Can it be range or table?

Comment: $C$1 is an absolute reference. The row and column won't change if you bring the formula down (up, left or right) to fill the other cells (or copy). C1 is relative reference. If you bring it down (up, left or right) to fill the other cell (for example cells below), it will change to C2, C3, etc. $ fixes (locks) the row or column.